# How to change textarea value after pushing another page?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, onsen-ui

I'm all new to angularjs/onsen in general. So i'm trying to actually select a contact form contact list and show the name in the textarea for the create a message page. I have this, but it is not working.

contacts.html

```
<div ng-controller="ContactsController" >
      <ons-list class="person-list" >
        <ons-list-header class="person-list-header" ng-init="people = contacts">{{char}}</ons-list-header>
          <ons-list-item class="person" modifier="tappable" ng-click="contactsBack("{{person.username}}")" ng-repeat="person in contacts | filter:searchInput">
            <ons-row>
              <ons-col width="40px">
                <img src="images/profile-image-0{{i}}.png" class="person-image">
              </ons-col>

              <ons-col class="person-name" >
                {{person.username}}
              </ons-col>
            </ons-row>
          </ons-list-item>
      </ons-list>
    </div>
```

message page

```
        <ons-row align="center">
        <ons-col width="290px">
            <div class="left">
                <input type="text" id ="contactName" class="text-input text-input--transparent" placeholder="Name" style="width: 100%">
            </div>
        </ons-col>

    <ons-col>
```

app.js

```
    $scope.contactsBack = function(name) {
  $scope.document.getElementById("contactName").value = name;

  $scope.navi.pushPage('message.html');
  }
```

I have included the function under 'ContactsController'

Comment: Your ng-click is not proper. it should be like - ng-click="contactsBack(person.username)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your mesaage page define field like this one.

Define your `contactName` using [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel).You don't need ID attribute or javascript method for this

And JS:

```
$scope.contactsBack = function(name) {
    $scope.contactName = name;

    $scope.navi.pushPage('message.html');
}
```

Angular uses [two-way data binding](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04) using which your field in message page is get populated with contact list.

EDIT 1 :
remove double quote
    ng-click="contactsBack({{person.username}})"

Comment: what about the ng-click="contactsBack("{{person.username}}")" ?

Comment: am i passing the username to the function in a right way?

Comment: Thank you Riyaj for your help, but it's not working for some reason!

Comment: are both the textarea and the function supposed to be under the same controller?

Comment: it actually redirects the page, but the name won't show in the textarea?